How would I do string comparison in awk with variable strings on both sides?
As a follow-up to my previous question, how would a similar string comparison be made when there are mutable characters on either side of it in the document?
As an example:
# test,date
"test1","27 March 2024 01:37 PM UTC"
"test2","13 April 2024 07:08 AM UTC"
"test4","13 April 2024 07:09 AM UTC"
"test5","13 April 2024 07:10 AM UTC"
"test6","13 April 2024 07:12 AM UTC"

How would the previous answer:
awk -F, -v date="$(date +'%B %Y')\"$" '/^[^#]/ && $2 ~ date{print $1}'

Be modified to print all the tests from this month (April 2024 at the time of writing)?

Compared how? Please [edit] and give us a specific example so we can understand. And what string? Please make sure your questions can stand on their own and we don't need to go and understand a previous question in order to be able to understand this one.

Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (including sample strings you want to compare, not just the file you want to compare them to) and the expected output given that input. Based on what I happen to know of your previous question, it sounds as if you're just asking how to write a regexp to compare March 2024 to March 2024 01:37 PM UTC" which I'm sure a quick google search could answer for you.

Ed morton's answer to your previous question would work just as well just by changing the contents of date to whatever you want to match in the second field, so date="February 2024"

@EdMorton Hopefully those edits are what you're referring to! Sorry for making an example out of context. I'd still like the current date to be processed.

@T145 keep in mind that this site is intended to be a directory where people with similar questions can find established answers, not just somewhere people can ask question to get new answers. When someone comes across this question in 10 years the "current date" for them won't be April 2024 and so won't match the input. Always provide specific, concrete values in your questions. The fact that outside of this question you need to get the current date by calling date is completely irrelevant to the question of how to match a specific date in a specific location of a specific field of a CSV.

I figured that's what all the hoopla was about. Thanks for the clarification!

I just noticed your subject line says "string comparison" - to be clear, you didn't ask for that in your previous question so neither my previous answer nor my answer here are doing string comparison, they're doing regexp comparison. If you need string comparison then please ask a new question with  sample input/output that demonstrate why you need that instead of regexp comparison (e.g. regexp metachars in the "date" to be matched) so we can test with it.

awk -F, -v date="$(date +'%B %Y')\"$"

is creating a regexp April 2024"$ stored in the variable date. That won't match your new input so just tweak it to a regexp that does match by changing \"$ to [^\"]*\"$ or whatever other matching regexp you prefer, e.g.:
$ awk -F, -v date="$(date +'%B %Y')[^\"]+\"$" '/^[^#]/ && $2 ~ date{print $1}' file
"test2"
"test4"
"test5"
"test6"

or possibly more robustly depending what other values can be in that 2nd field:
$ awk -F, -v date="$(date +'%B %Y') [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M [[:upper:]]+\"$" '/^[^#]/ && $2 ~ date{print $1}' file
"test2"
"test4"
"test5"
"test6"


Thanks; I was definitely over-complicating it. Is there a way to use wildcards to make it Mawk-compatible?

If Mawk doesn't understand [^\"]*\"" then I can't imagine what it WOULD understand as that syntax has been around since the first proto-regexp crawled out of the ocean and grew legs (and you need to get a much more modern version of awk!).
